# Why is the ternary operator not working in my code?

Tags: c++, if-statement, return, language-lawyer, ternary-operator

I have the following piece of code

```
mystack.empty() ? return 1 : return 0;
```

which looks perfect from the syntax point of view but whenever I try to run it throws an error saying

> [Error] expected ':' before 'return'

and

> [Error] expected primary-expression before 'return'

Do ternary operator don't work with return statements or is there something wrong with the code? And I guess the code is self explanatory.

Thank you.

Comment: Which language is this? `return` is usually a statement while the ternary operator requires two expressions e.g. `return (mystack.empty() ? 1 : 0);`.

Comment: @EdHeal What's the problem here?

Comment: @Lee I'm writing this in C++

Comment: It is incorrect syntax.

Comment: @Lee Your comment helped me. Thank you. You can post it as an answer, I'll mark it correct. And EdHeal I didn't know that I couldn't do that way. Thank you anyway.

Comment: the ternary operator is not a different way to write an if - it doesn't take statements as you seem to think. @Lee has an example of use.

Comment: I think I need to tell you a trick. You can wrap the sides in `[]{ ... ;}()` braces and it actually becomes valid!¹¹

Comment: ... but a bit unreadable

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Nah, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

The syntax is invalid. [Ternary conditional operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) requires its operands to be [expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Primary_expressions), but `return 1` and `return 0` are not.

On the other hand, [return statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return) could be used with an (optional) expression, such as a ternary conditional operator:

> attr(optional) return expression(optional) ;  (1)

So you could/should write it as

```
return mystack.empty() ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Technically `return 1` is not a statement either (`return 1;` would be)

Comment: @M.M So is it just an invalid representation? Neither statement nor expression.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't meet the grammar for conditional operator because it's not an expression (and for that purpose it doesn't matter what it is, if anything)

Comment: Or you could use simply `return mystack.empty();`

Comment: @PeteBecker yeah I could have used that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

return is an statement and rule is that you cant invoke a statement into a expression.

try reformatting code and using following (Assuming that function return a boolean value)

```
return  mystack.empty()? 1:0;
```